# What are some of the key features that are currently absent in open-source AMLs like Pyomo, JuMP, Gurobipy

Tags: pyomo, gurobipy, jump

What are the some of prominent technical features (which may or may not be part of commercial Algebraic Modeling Languages (AMLs) such as GAMS or AMPL) which are currently lacking in open-source AMLs like Pyomo, JuMP etc.?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but if you have any suggestions for JuMP, please open a feature request: https://github.com/jump-dev/JuMP.jl/issues. One example we're looking at is adding support for units https://github.com/jump-dev/JuMP.jl/issues/1350. Another is better support for constraint programming: https://github.com/jump-dev/JuMP.jl/issues/2227.

Comment: Suggestions for [Timefold](https://timefold.ai/) (open source, Apache License, java) are welcome here:
https://github.com/TimefoldAI/timefold-solver/discussions

Answer (score 6):

Pulp is missing the Python Cplex Piecewize feature, and IF/ELSE features.
Caylie Cincera has a nice video about this, she does a Piecewize included constraints optimization using Pulp:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0zP74EdmN0w